# linux knife (chef) proxy

Tags: proxy, chef

I have

```
chef_server_url 'https://192.168.1.1/organizations/orgname'
```

in my

```
.chef/knife.rb
```

along with

```
knife[:bootstrap_proxy] = "http://172.16.1.254:3128/"
knife[:http_proxy] = "http://172.16.1.254:3128/"
```

knife status shows me

```
knife status
ERROR: Errno::ENETUNREACH: Failed to open TCP connection to 192.168.1.1:443 (Network is unreachable - connect(2) for "192.168.1.1" port 443)
```

So, proxy settings is NOT in action.

How to resolve it?

sock 5 proxy for me is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check https://docs.chef.io/proxies/ and `https_proxy` settings

Comment: wokring. I want to emphasize that is is Linux env, not the knife config variables
now it reports 
knife status
ERROR: EOFError: end of file reached
dont know why but thanks anyway!

Comment: wokring partly.
knife  status --verbose
INFO: Using configuration from /home/user/.chef/knife.rb
INFO: Sending query: *:*
ERROR: EOFError: end of file reached

I use sock5 type of proxy.

Comment: with http proxy
INFO: Sending query: *:*
ERROR: The data in your request was invalid
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/response.rb:331:in `stream_check': undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I suggest to add https_proxy=http://... knife ... (in front of knife command). since knife prefer all_proxy before http_proxy and https_proxy, also it don't support sock5 type of proxy - this is underwork  as a whole chef is (including knife etc).  :( avoid to use chef as a whole.

Comment: **berks upload** still don't work. can't upload the cookbook :(

Comment: user http_proxy=.. berks .. to make it work, https_proxy don't work.